# Aegeus, king of Naxos?

Tags: greek, myth-identification, theseus

... does anyone out there have any idea or original source for this 'Aegeus' myth quoted in the link below?

https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/heroes/aegeus/

The Origins of Aegeus
Titan of the sea, father of Theseus

Aegeus was king of Naxos for some time, but when he married Aethra, she became queen instead. He left after she gave birth to Theseus, and when he returned, Aegeus battled Eumolpus for the position of titan king.

Aegeus told his people to stop attacking Athens while he was gone, but they did not stop. When Aegeus realized that they would never stop without help, he asked Theseus to go into battle and stop them. Theseus was victorious, and Aegeus resumed his rule.......

I've never come across it and can't find another reference; it seems like a mixture of other more familiar Theseus/Aegeus myths.... I've tried contacting the site without success.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I do not remember ever seeing Aegeus and Eumolpus being referred as titans. Also the site seems like blog.

Comment: Also Naxos is associated to Crete, is where Theseus left Ariadne not related to Aegeus as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know, as I said I haven't found anything that supports it, and I've repeatedly tried to contact the site... however most of the other information on the site is pretty good and this myth seems very spacific, sad no citation. ... just wondered if I'd missed something.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I can't spell specific !